# Swift Realm backup and restore the realm data

Tags: swift, realm, backup, restore, migrate

I am currently creating two functions that backup the realm file on backup URL and restore it when required.

This is for the purpose of preventing loss data while using the app with the Realm.

For example:

```
Backup URL: .../user1-server-backup.realm
Restore URL: .../user1-server.realm
```

- The backup function does copy the realm file on restore URL to the
  backup URL.
- And restore function migrates the realm file on backup URL    to the
  restore URL.

I already made a backup function using the writeCopy function.

```
class func backupLocalStore(storeBackupDirectoryURL: URL) -> Bool {

    let user = CSDefaults.curEmail.replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: "")
    let sAp = CSDefaults.getPassAndServerFrom(email: user)
    let prefix = sAp.1.components(separatedBy: ".")[0]
    let file = "\(user)-\(prefix)-backup.realm"

    let backupURL = Realm.Configuration().fileURL?.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent(file)
    // To be implemented
    // Optionally wrap in a write transaction to
    // prevent other changes happening
    realm.beginWrite()
    do {
        try realm.writeCopy(toFile: backupURL!)
    } catch {
        // Error backing up data
        return false
    }
    realm.cancelWrite()
    return true
}
```

Now I am going to make the restore function that migrates the realm file on backup URL to the restore URL.

I have no idea how to create this function with correct migration block so that the app can work properly with the backup file.

I am using Swift 5 and CocoaPod RealmSwift 3.17.3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to have Realm use the replacement file?

Comment: I am just asking how to restore the realm file to the existing URL.

Comment: Asking *how to restore the realm file to the existing URL* is a bit vague. Are you asking for code to copy a file from one URL to another? It looks like you already have that - is it not working? Are there any errors? What is the specific issue you're having with that task?

Comment: Yes, actually I have implemented it. But I am just wondering if it works vice versa.
e.g. I am going to use the backed up Realm instead of current Realm.

Comment: You can use any Realm you like. However, and this is super important - In a nutshell, once Realm connects to a data source, it will continue to use that data source as long as the objects are not released, even if the actual file is deleted or moved. The way around that is to encapsulate the Realm calls into an autorelease pool so that those objects can be released when the Realm is deleted and replaced with a different Realm file.